# How do I set SVN url?

Tags: svn

I have svn working, because when I type in `svn help` it gives the svn commands showing me it's installed. How do I set my svn url? I have my SVN via Beanstalk, I just need to figure out how to get the files from beanstalk to my computer using my Mac oSX terminal :)

Comment: Have you started a new project or put a certain directory under SVN control yet?

Comment: i have created the folder but have not done anything to link an url to that folder. is this where i am missing the last step - linking the svn url to the folder?

Comment: Do you want to create a copy of an existsing SVN repository, or do you want to create your own (empty) repository?

Comment: i would like to pull all files from a working svn repository via Beanstalk. Just need to pull the files from Beanstalk to my cpu.

Comment: Are you trying to set up a new working copy of a project that already exists in a SVN repository somewhere, or are you trying to create a new repository for a project that isn't yet under SVN control?

Comment: i am trying to set up a working copy of a project that already exists in SVN repository on Beanstalk.

Answer (score 6):

```
svn co <url> <path>
```

will checkout the working copy from repository to `path`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts in Subversion, the client and the server.

The client is what you have just tested, it can connect to a server to checkout and commit files, among other things. You can find a well-written manual [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html).

The server hosts the repositories, the data of the projects that is shared among developers.

If you are on your own, you have to setup a server, you can check [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.html) how to do that. If you don't want to go through the trouble of setting up a server, there are services like [Google Code](http://code.google.com/), that will host it for you (but then it will be public).

I'm afraid you will have to precise your question to get further help :-)

Comment: thanks. i have edited my question which hopefully helps others in helping me :)

Comment: +1 for the link to the manual, but -1 for the misinformation about requiring a server. 

If you are working independently, you do not need to set up a server. You can keep the repository on the same machine as your working copies and access it with the subversion client using URL's begginging with "file:".

Comment: Once you have created a repository there (they have a FAQ), you can use the checkout command (co): `svn co <URL> [<directory>]` to do a first checkout to your local <directory>.